# QtLua capture slider value change

Tags: lua, qslider

I am trying to make a simple UI using qtlua, in which I want to capture the slider value everytime it changes. I tried to connect to the valueChanged() signal, but qlua gives me the following error:

```
cannot find source signal valueChanged()
```

The code snippet looks like this:

```
slide = (widget.sliderLight)
    print(slide)
    qt.connect(slide, 'valueChanged()',
                 function()
                     print('Value: ', slide.value)
                 end)
```

So just a test to print everytime the value changes. But I cannot get it working. The documentation for the qtlua doesn't have a class for qslider, so that's a dead end for me. And I couldn't find any examples for using qtlua with a slider that is connected to the valueChanged() signal. The only example I found was with the test.lua in the qtuiloader example, but that uses a timer, which I assume is pooled at regular interval. My aim is to hook this up to an image processing system, so it would be useful if I could tie it to when the value changes, rather than patch in with a timer and a check system. I am pretty new to qt, so must be missing something. Any and all help would be really appreciated!
Oh and I made sure I have tracking checkbox checked in the qtdesigner, to ensure that the signal is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I dug around a little more in the documentation of QT for the valueChanged() slot. Turns out, the function signature has an int argument in it, so the Lua connect code was looking for a function signature without any arguments. Modifying the above code to the following works as expected:

```
slide = (widget.sliderLight)
    print(slide)
    qt.connect(slide, 'valueChanged(int)',
                 function(w)
                     print('Value: ', w)
                 end)
```

Declaring a function with the same signature also passes in the required value, which saves me an explicit value query.
Hopefully, this will be useful for someone someday.